# How does Application.Volatile update before even being run?

Tags: vba

If I add the following line to a UDF

```
Application.Volatile (True)
```

it will update the function immediately without a need to reopen the workbook or run through the function first.  This is not the case with similar functions such as

```
Application.Onkey
```

Edit:

I should also note that

```
Application.Volatile (False)
```

DOES need to be run first to take effect

Comment: `Application.Volatile` forces the function to be re-calculated whenever a calculation takes place - so essentially it is triggered by any of the `_Calculate` events. If you enter `=Now()` into a cell and keep pressing **F9** you will see that the result updates every time

Comment: So, ...what's the question?

Comment: The question is how does the application immediately recognize the function as volatile without any need to compile it or reopen the document or run through the function first